# Working with a dequeued, dequeueReusableCell - textField of cell when after being dequeued

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm working with a VC that has as a variable amount of cells. Each cell contains an ingredient, as well as a percentage for the amount. I added an `inputAccessoryView` to the textField keyboard that has a `next` button for navigation to the next row's textField.

This is all working fine, however I've come into a problem when a cell isn't loaded on screen.

The code is very simple:

```
func setNextResponder(for indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let index = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: 0)
    guard let nextCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as? Cell
    else { return }
    nextCell.materialAmountTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Is there anyway to force the VC to load that cell? Preferably without having to scroll to that cell.

Comment: “Preferably without having to scroll to that cell” ... If that cell is not visible, wouldn’t the data entry be very confusing, not letting them see what they're typing? It seems to me that scrolling it into view would be the right solution. I'm wondering why you wouldn't want it to be visible.

Comment: Hey Rob, that is true. It's not the end of the world if I need to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and called

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: newIndexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
```

before setting the next cell's textField as the first responder.